# In Iguazio cluster, when initing a spark session without any configuration modification, what is the default spark.executor.memory set to?

Tags: apache-spark, mlops

When initing a spark session without any configuration modification, what is the default spark.executor.memory set to?

Answer (score 0):

It is 1g based on Spark specification, full detail see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html